# MySQL: Select all rows from select distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I would like to do a specific query

```
select distinct name 
from tablename
```

to remove duplicates. But this gives me only the names. From 'select distinct name from table' I would like all columns returned with one where condition:

```
select * 
from tablename 
where value= 1
```

I tried this:

```
select * 
from tablename 
where value = 1 and exists (select distinct name 
                            from tablename)
```

Unfortunately it returns the same data as:

```
select * 
from tablename 
where value = 1
```

Which means that there is a fundamental flaw in my query.

Could someone help me with my query. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Formatted text, please. (Not images.)

Comment: have you tried using a 'group by'?   Is any aggregation required?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this `select field1, field2, field3 from tablename group by field2`

Comment: This doesn't remove duplicates. So it doesn't work for me. I need to remove all rows where "name" column has duplicates.

Comment: Could you provide a sample dataset, showing what you want, for reference?

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the id where you have duplicates:

```
select distinct id
from table1
group by id
having count(id)>1
```

and you can put

```
having count(id)=1
```

if you want to know the ones that don have duplicates

Comment: This doesn't return all the columns. So it doesn't work for me. I need to remove all rows where "name" column has duplicates.